# Error al mostrar un control en el front-end wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hola muy buenas quisieran que me ayudaran con mi problema, estos días he estado programado un thema wordpress y me vino a la mente hacer algo que he visto en muchos temas que es hacer un control que sirva para ordenar tanto los metas, titulo e imagen destacada de la entrada, por suerte encontré uno por Internet y me ahorre de programarlo,cuando toco mostrarlo en el front-end no pasa nada no se si estoy haciendo algo malo en el código ya que soy un poco novato en php, aquí esta lo que he echo.

```
    function Snove_Card_order(){
        $sv_card_order = get_theme_mod( 'Card_order', '' );
        if ( !empty( $sv_card_order )) {
            foreach ($sv_card_order  as $card_order) {
    
                switch ($Card_order) {
    
                    case 'Imagen_Destacada':
                    Snove_Imagen_Destacada();
                    break;
                
                    case 'Titulo':
                    Snove_Titulo();
                    break;
                
                    case 'Meta':
                    Snove_Meta();
                    break;
                
                }
        
            }
        }
    }
```

y aquí el control

```
$wp_customize->add_control( new Snove_Pill_Checkbox_Custom_Control( $wp_customize, 'Card_order',
            array(
                'label' => __( 'Card order', 'Snove' ),
                'section' => 'Card_Order',
                'input_attrs' => array(
                    'sortable' => true,
                    'fullwidth' => true,
                ),
                'choices' => array(
                    'Imagen_Destacada' => __( 'Imagen Destacada', 'Snove' ),
                    'Titulo' => __( 'Titulo', 'Snove' ),
                    'Meta' => __( 'Meta', 'Snove'  ),
                )
            )
    ) );
```

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

el código aparentemente es válido, lo que no sé es si has registrado correctamente el control, te pongo como quedaría el código en el functions.php de tu tema para el registro correcto del control. Ya dirás si este era el problema. Un saludo.

```
<?php

function Snove_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->add_control( new Snove_Pill_Checkbox_Custom_Control( $wp_customize, 'Card_order',
                array(
                    'label' => __( 'Card order', 'Snove' ),
                    'section' => 'Card_Order',
                    'input_attrs' => array(
                        'sortable' => true,
                        'fullwidth' => true,
                    ),
                    'choices' => array(
                        'Imagen_Destacada' => __( 'Imagen Destacada', 'Snove' ),
                        'Titulo' => __( 'Titulo', 'Snove' ),
                        'Meta' => __( 'Meta', 'Snove'  ),
                    )
                )
        ) );
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'Snove_customize_register' );

?>
```

Comment: No, el control esta registrado correctamente ya que le hice echo a get_theme_mod( 'Card_order', '' ); y me devolvió los valores del array es decir; Imagen_Destacada,Titulo,Meta, pero al hacer lo del switch no manda nada y no se por que.